# Missing nodes in mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I've created this mindmap but some nodes are missing. The colors are displayed correctly and the text is at the right position.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{alizarin}{rgb}{0.82, 0.1, 0.26}
\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{calpolypomonagreen}{rgb}{0.12, 0.3, 0.17}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{mahogany}{rgb}{0.75, 0.25, 0.0}
\definecolor{mikadoyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.77, 0.05}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\tikzset{concept/.append style={fill={none}}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap, concept color=black, text=black,
                    level 1/.style={level distance=5cm},
                    level 2/.style={level distance=4cm},
                    level 3/.style={level distance=4cm}]
  \node[concept] {ResClue}
    child[concept color=alizarin, grow=0]{ node[concept]{Parse Eingabedatei}}
    child[concept color=amber, grow=50]{ node[concept]{Bereite Daten anhand von Parametereigenschaften auf}
      child[concept color=amber!70, grow=30]{node[concept]{Weise den Variablen Werte zu}}
      child[concept color=amber!70, grow=90]{node[concept]{Wiederhole Werte}}
    }
    child[concept color=ao, grow=100]{ node{Konvertiere Einheiten}
      child[concept color=ao!70]{ node{Konvertiere Einheit von Variable}}
    }
    child[concept color=calpolypomonagreen, grow=150]{ node{Erzeuge Geometrie des Rechengitters}}
    child[concept color=lava, grow=200]{ node{Weise Gitterblockeigenschaften zu}}
    child[concept color=mahogany, grow=250]{ node{Erzeuge lineare Gleichungssysteme} 
      child[concept color=mahogany!70, grow=210]{ node{Lineares Gleichungssystem Druckgleichung} 
        child[concept color=mahogany!50, grow=140]{ node{Relative Permeabilitäten und Kapillardruck nach Brooks-Corey}}
        child[concept color=mahogany!50, grow=200]{ node{1-Punkt-Aufwindapproximation von $k_{r\alpha}$}}
        child[concept color=mahogany!50, grow=270]{ node{Randbedingungen einfügen}}
      }
      child[concept color=mahogany!70, grow=300]{ node{Lineares Gleichungssystem Sättigungsgleichung}}
    }
    child[concept color=mikadoyellow, grow=300]{ node{Löse lineare Gleichungssysteme}}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! You don't tell those nodes to use the style `concept` the way you do for the ones which are drawn correctly. So the nodes are the default style, which doesn't draw them etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the 'missing' nodes and the 'non-missing' ones is that the `concept` style is applied to the latter but not the former. The nodes are all there, but they use the default node style which doesn't draw the border.

The solution is simply to apply the `concept` style to all the nodes in the mind map.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\definecolor{alizarin}{rgb}{0.82, 0.1, 0.26}
\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{calpolypomonagreen}{rgb}{0.12, 0.3, 0.17}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{mahogany}{rgb}{0.75, 0.25, 0.0}
\definecolor{mikadoyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.77, 0.05}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\tikzset{concept/.append style={fill={none}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    small mindmap,
    concept color=black,
    text=black,
    every node/.append style={concept},
    level 1/.style={level distance=5cm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=4cm},
    level 3/.style={level distance=4cm}
  ]
  \node[concept] {ResClue}
  child[concept color=alizarin, grow=0]{ node[concept]{Parse Eingabedatei}}
  child[concept color=amber, grow=50]{ node[concept]{Bereite Daten anhand von Parametereigenschaften auf}
    child[concept color=amber!70, grow=30]{node[concept]{Weise den Variablen Werte zu}}
    child[concept color=amber!70, grow=90]{node[concept]{Wiederhole Werte}}
  }
  child[concept color=ao, grow=100]{ node{Konvertiere Einheiten}
    child[concept color=ao!70]{ node{Konvertiere Einheit von Variable}}
  }
  child[concept color=calpolypomonagreen, grow=150]{ node{Erzeuge Geometrie des Rechengitters}}
  child[concept color=lava, grow=200]{ node{Weise Gitterblockeigenschaften zu}}
  child[concept color=mahogany, grow=250]{ node{Erzeuge lineare Gleichungssysteme}
    child[concept color=mahogany!70, grow=210]{ node{Lineares Gleichungssystem Druckgleichung}
      child[concept color=mahogany!50, grow=140]{ node{Relative Permeabilitäten und Kapillardruck nach Brooks-Corey}}
      child[concept color=mahogany!50, grow=200]{ node{1-Punkt-Aufwindapproximation von $k_{r\alpha}$}}
      child[concept color=mahogany!50, grow=270]{ node{Randbedingungen einfügen}}
    }
    child[concept color=mahogany!70, grow=300]{ node{Lineares Gleichungssystem Sättigungsgleichung}}
  }
  child[concept color=mikadoyellow, grow=300]{ node{Löse lineare Gleichungssysteme}}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 'found' nodes]

Comment: This needs tinkering a bit to neaten up the overwide text, obviously.  Hopefully the OP speaks the language it is written in ;).